# New branch creation in Git using old commits in existing branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a stable point commit/tag b1. Now I want to create another branch, say b2, from that stable commit/tag, and work on it.

I am thinking I should do this:

```
$ git checkout b1.
$ git fetch --tags
$ git checkout tags/my_stable_tag
```

Now create and move this code to new branch b2:

```
$ git checkout -b b2
```

To reflect this branch in remote repo, do git push:

```
$ git push origin
```

Is this proper way to do what I intended to do?

Comment: Does it do what you meant to do? Are you having trouble with it, or are you asking if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure, whether is this correct way or not, if i do push it can mess up remote git repo, which i dont want, so let me know is this correct or is there any better way to do it. thanks

Comment: It's ok. All I can suggest is to skip first step, because all tags are not branch relative.

Comment: As long as you don't push nothing bad (that cannot be undone) happens. You can change your local repository, try one thing or another and tweak it until you are satisfied by the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be able to use:

```
git checkout -b <new_branch> [<start point>]
```

i.e. in you case, simply:

```
git checkout -b b2 tags/my_stable_tag
```

this should work regardless of where you currently are in the tree.